# How to get reproducible results with Keras/Tensorflow on different computers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

We are working on a deep learning project with a friend, and we would like to train the same model on our 2 different computers and get the same results. Is there a way we can do that?

Tensorflow version is 2.5.0

What we tried so far:
At the start of our code, in the first line of the main function, we set the Python Hash Seed to 0.

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(0)
```

After that, in the training function we set the seeds appropriately.

```
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

On one computer, two runs with the same seed gives us the same result, however on the 2 different computers, the results are different.
For example, with seed = 1, on my pc, the loss is around 0.09, but on my friend's it is lower than 0.06.
Why is that, and how can we solve it?

Comment: Can you try update tensorflow to `tf-nightly` and use `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed`?

Comment: It does exactly the same as my solution. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed